# How to use Django/Nodejs with DDEV

Tags: node.js, django, ddev

I work a lot with [DDEV](https://ddev.readthedocs.io/) on my PHP projects and love the features DDEV offers.
Since I also work with Django and NodeJS projects I would like to use them in combination with DDEV. Officially these are not yet supported in the current version (1.18) but maybe someone has already found a solution?

Comment: Well, lots of people use it with nodejs, but not sure about django. Although python3 is included... so it might work just fine, but you'd probably want your own nginx or apache config to front django. For node, you'll see some answers here, https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bddev%5D+nodejs - and I'm happy to help you along the way!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a quick and dirty answer on django, I'd like to get you started with a simple and probably inadequate approach, but it shows how easy it is to add something like django. We'll just use the django dev server.

1. Make a directory, I called mine `dj` and `cd dj`
2. `ddev config --auto`
3. Add to the `.ddev/config.yaml`:

```yaml
webimage_extra_packages: [python3-django]
hooks:
  post-start:
    - exec: python3 manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
```

4. Add `.ddev/docker-compose.django.yaml`:

```yaml
version: "3.6"
services:
  web:
    expose:
      - 8000
    environment:
      - HTTP_EXPOSE=80:8000
      - HTTPS_EXPOSE=443:8000
    healthcheck:
      test: "true"
```

5. `ddev start`
6. `ddev ssh` and create a trivial django project:
7. `django-admin startproject dj .`
8. Add to your `dj/settings.py` `ALLOWED_HOSTS = ["dj.ddev.site"]`
9. Exit back out to the host with `ctrl-D` or `exit` and `ddev start`
10. You should be able to access the trivial project at `https://dj.ddev.site`

Note that as you proceed, you'll probably want to end up starting the django server another way, or more likely actually front it by the ddev-webserver nginx server, which would be more natural (as in https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/web-server/app-gateway-uwsgi-django/). But for now, this is a simple demonstration. Happy to help you as you go along.